# Can a list of connected devices to a WPA2 WiFi hotspot be stolen, without connecting to the network itself?

Tags: security, wifi

Is it possible for let’s say a hacker to obtain a list of users connected to a WPA2 secured WiFi, if he doesn't know the password and will not be able to obtain it in any way ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes kind of.
You can read out the MAC - Addresses of connected devices without having the passkey. You just would have to run a passive scan.

The MAC - Address is not necessarily unique as you could change it on most devices.

Needless to say:
It's illegal to obtain such data in other Wifi's than your own as this is a breach in personal privacy.